# Warrantless entry and search with restricted PAL?

Tags: canada, firearms

I have been told that since I have my restricted Possession and Acquisition Licence (PAL) (for firearms), police may enter and search my home without providing a warrant whenever they choose. They are telling me it's due to Bill C-68.

Is this true, or simply a misinterpretation?

Comment: For the benefit of future readers it would be helpful to explain what a "restricted PAL" is as that is not obvious from either the question or the answer and abbreviations often fall out of common use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sections 102-105 of the [Firearms Act](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/PDF/F-11.6.pdf) is what's relevant, in the section on inspections. First, this section pertains to firearms inspectors, not just every police officer. Section 102 says that

> an inspector may at any reasonable time enter and inspect any place
>   where the inspector believes on reasonable grounds a business is being
>   carried on or there is a record of a business, any place in which the
>   inspector believes on reasonable grounds there is a gun collection or
>   a record in relation to a gun collection or any place in which the
>   inspector believes on reasonable grounds there is a prohibited firearm
>   or there are more than 10 firearms

Section 103 says

> The owner or person in charge of a place that *is inspected* by an
>   inspector under section 102 and every person found in the place shall
>
> (a) give the inspector all reasonable assistance to enable him or her
>   to carry out the inspection and exercise any power conferred by
>   section 102; and
>
> (b)provide the inspector with any information relevant to the
>   enforcement of this Act or the regulations that he or she may
>   reasonably require

The significance of the underlining is that *if* you allow the inspector in, you have to cooperate. But Sect 104 says:

> (1) An  inspector  may  not  enter  a  dwelling-house under section
>   102 except
>
> (a)on reasonable notice to the owner or occupant, except  where  a 
>   business  is  being  carried  on  in  the dwelling-house; *and*
>
> (b)  **with the consent of the occupant or under a warrant**

So I think it's fair to say that that is a misinterpretation.

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I was looking for!